# Partial template specialization match differs between VS2019 and VS2022 when compiling

Tags: c++, c++14

Following code is a runnable sample which is a simplification of our production code.
When compiling with **VS 2019 (Platform toolset 142)** the output is **2**.
However, when compiling in **VS 2022 (Platform toolset 143)** the output is **1**.

Why is that? and how can we make sure the desired (same for both toolsets) partial specialization is matched?

`Example.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class TestB {
public:
    using Type = T;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename ... PP>
class TestA
{
public:
    static void print() { std::cout << "1\n"; };
};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename P1, typename ... PP>
class TestA<T1, T2, P1, PP...> : public TestA<T1, typename P1::Type, PP...>
{
};

template <typename T1, typename ... PP>
class TestA<T1, T1, PP...>
{
public:
    static void print() { std::cout << "2\n"; };
};

int main(int, char* [])
{
    TestA<int, int, TestB<int>, TestB<double>>::print();
    return 0;
}
```

Expected is that when template param 1 and 2 are equal, it should match the final specialization (represented by print `2`).
In reality in production code we map up certain parameters of the object when we hit this spec.

Comment: The way that these templates are structured is that overload resolution depends on the compiler deciding which potential template is "more specific". This has always been a source of compiler bugs, and the different results don't surprise me. I try to avoid designing my templates so that the "more specific" one is fairly easy to determine, and avoid giving the compiler more opportunities to blow it.

Comment: MSVC seems to be the only major compiler to even accept the code: https://godbolt.org/z/axe1KGb49.

Comment: clang and gcc both think this is ambiguous: https://godbolt.org/z/dPdv7h15M What is the goal of this code? Which out of `1` and `2` is the "correct" answer?

Comment: Can you explain what this template should do? I see you are trying to use SFINAE, but I can't put finger on it what is exact aim here. What is the purpose of last specialization?

Comment: There has been changes to overload resoultion that *might* affect this. [1395. Partial ordering of variadic templates reconsidered](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1395.html)

Comment: @MarekR, its a simplified version of our code only. Expected is that when template param 1 and 2 are equal it should match the final specialization where we map up some parameters on the object (not present in this code, but is represented by the print 2)

Comment: @AlanBirtles, we expect `2`. in our production code case `1` is not specified so when that matches we get a `base class is undefined` compilation error

Comment: Adding specialization for `class TestA<T1, T1, P1, PP...>` should solve the issue.

Comment: Unrelated: `int main(int, char[])` is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question might have been poorly phrased since it was a bit tricky to create a simple test case the resembled the actual code.

However, a colleague found a solution that seem to work as expected. Adding a metafunction that checks if T1 and T2 are the same allows the compiler to select the correct specialization.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class TestB {
public:
    using Type = T;
};

template <typename ... PP>
class TestA;

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename P1, typename ... PP>
class TestA<T1, T2, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<T1, T2>>, P1, PP...> : public TestA<T1, typename P1::Type, void, PP...>
{

};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename ... PP>
class TestA<T1, T2, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T1, T2>>, PP...>
{
public:
    void print() const { std::cout << typeid(*this).name() << std::endl; };
};

int main(int, char* [])
{
    TestA<int, double, void, TestB<int>, TestB<double>>().print();
    TestA<int, int, void, TestB<int>, TestB<double>>().print();
    return 0;
}
```

Tank you all for your effort to help.

Answer (score 1):

You miss a case to remove ambiguity:

```
template <typename T1, typename P1, typename ... PP>
class TestA<T1, T1, P1, PP...>
{
public:
    static void print() { std::cout << "2\n"; };
};
```

and so your case 2 can be simplified (as above case would handle non-empty pack):

```
template <typename T1>
class TestA<T1, T1>
{
public:
    static void print() { std::cout << "2 final\n"; };
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/155jG6bfr)

Answer (score 0):

In your first specialization, there is no direct connection of `T2` and `P1::type`. If you fix it to

```cpp
template <typename T1, typename P1, typename ... PP>
class TestA<T1, typename P1::type, P1, PP...> : public TestA<T1, typename P1::Type, PP...>
{
};
```

the ambiguity seems to be resolved. https://godbolt.org/z/hbP1qTc3e